# C How to take multiple files for arguments?

Tags: c, file, arguments, text-files

How would you ask for the user to input files as arguments to be used (as many as they would like)? Also How would you print to a file?

```
scanf("%s", user_filename);

    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen (user_filename, "r");
```

I have tried doing various things to it but I can only get it to take one file.

Comment: could you be more specific with your question , and if possible show us som code

Comment: I assume that the user would input a string (`char*`) and then you would parse the string into zero or more filepaths (`char*`). Then create file pointers (`FILE`) for the filepaths and operate on the files via the file pointers.

Comment: Do you mean one at a time, or a whitespace-separated list of file names all entered on the same line?

Comment: @WhozCraig yes all on one line just separated by a space so a.txt b.txt...

Comment: Yeah you're going to need a tokenizer to pull those out of a single string, and I warn you with modern file systems supporting white-space-embedded names, (i.e. "My File Name.txt") this is not going to be as trivial as you may think.

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't passing the file names on the command line?

Comment: @mbratch I dont know I just found out about this stuff and im so confused about files.

Comment: If you pass he file names as command line arguments, `mycommand file_name1 file_name2` etc, and your main is `int main( int argc, char *argv[] )` then the array `argv[]` starting at index `1` has your file names all collected for you. So `argv[1]` will be "filename1", `argv[2]` will be "filename2", etc.

Comment: @mbratch ok I've gotten all that but what do i do now if I want to the next command argv[2]

Comment: @MelMoore I've given more detail in my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to pass some file names to your C program is to pass them as arguments to your C program.

Arguments are passed to a C program using the parameters to `main`:

```
int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    ...
}
```

The value `argc` indicates how many parameters there are, and `argv[]` is an array of string pointers containing the arguments. Note that the first argument at index `0` (the string pointed to by `argv[0]`) is the command name itself. The rest of the arguments passed to the command are in `argv[1]`, `argv[2]`, and so on.

If you compile your program and call it like this:

```
my_prog foo.txt bar.txt bah.txt
```

Then the value of `argc` will be `4` (remember it includes the command) and the `argv` values will be:

```
argv[0] points to "my_prog"
argv[1] points to "foo.txt"
argv[2] points to "bar.txt"
argv[3] points to "bah.txt"
```

In your program then, you only need to check `argc` for how many parameters there are. If `argc > 1`, then you have at least one parameter starting at `argv[1]`:

```
int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    int i;
    FILE *fp;

    // If there are no command line parameters, complain and exit
    //
    if ( argc < 2 )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "Usage: %s some_file_names\n", argv[0] );
        return 1;  // This exits the program, but you might choose to continue processing
                   // the other files.
    }

    for ( i = 1; i < argc; i++ )
    {
        if ( (fp = fopen(argv[i], "r")) == NULL )
        {
            fprintf( stderr, "%s: Gah! I could not open file named %s!\n", argv[0], argv[i] );
            return 2;
        }

        // Do some stuff with file named argv[i], file pointer fp

        ...
        fclose( fp );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This is just one of several different ways to do it (functionally and stylistically), depending upon how you need to process the files.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying the parameters that is where I was confused the most.

Comment: How would I go about using argv with File_%03d.png?

Comment: @MarcusJ could you be more specific? Are you talking about passing the string ` ℅03d.png` as an argument to the command? Or do you really want your program to find all the files in a specified folder matching a particular pattern?

Comment: I want to be able to run my program with the command: ProgramName /Path/Image_%03d.png OutputFile.

I've seen many programs support this syntax so that leads me to believe there's a function like getopt that handles such a thing, but I can't find it. maybe my googling is just bad.

Comment: @MarcusJ you could do that. In that case, `argv[1]` will point to the string, `"/Path/Image_%03d.png"`. You'll need to write some code that translates `%03d` into a wildcard format that [`FindFirstFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364418%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) understands. But the better way to do it is to let the shell sort out the enumeration of files and use a shell-recognized wildcard argument, *e.g.*, `ProgramName /Path/Image_[0-9][0-9][0-9].png OutputFile`, then your program will see each of the `png` files individually in the `argv` array.

Comment: I'll look into that I'd prefer to avoid relying on different shells because I'm trying to be as platform independent as possible, so I'll probably go with the first choice, thanks.